# Hard Drive Failure? Windows formatting incorrect disk on install?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, windows-installation

I believe I had a hard drive failure recently and I am trying to install windows on any one of my drives.

I have a specific drive that I'd like to install on.  When I load windows from a bootable USB, I go to advanced install and I see all of my drives.  The drive I wish to install on is `disk 2`.  I've 'deleted', 'formatted' and 'cleaned' the drive.  When I go to install windows on it, It errors out before it can start transferring files.  I get an error that say s

> Windows could not format a partition on disk 0.  The error occurred while preparing the computer's system volumne.  Error code: 0x800770057

The thing is, I'm trying to install on `disk 2`.  Why is it talking about `disc 0`?

Also, when I try to format, clear, delete and install on `disc 1`, I get the same error.  I do not want to format disc 0, though when I get back to the disk list screen it shows I have 100% of `disc 0` available which makes me feel like it's already formatted that drive.

What is blocking me from installing windows on multiple drives?  Should I take all of the drives out except for the one I want to install on?

Comment: How many physical disks do you have, I doubt, you have 3 separate drives

Comment: @Ramhound I do have 3 separate drives.  1x 120GB SSD, 1x 230GB SSD, 1x 700GB HDD

Comment: Your choosing the disk based on the identification number or the size of the drive?  Have you tried to disconnect the failing drive?  What was stored on the failing drive?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm about to open it and start swapping disks.  My system drive is just dedicated to system and programs.  I save everything important on the 700gb HDD, so I'm not worried if the system drive is the one that failed.  What I'm really worried about now is if the windows install happened to format my 700gb drive.  It shows 692/692 free which is a bad sign....

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a destination drive for your operating system, @ntgCleaner, you should unplug all secondary SATA devices connected to the motherboard while Windows is installing. Having more than 1 destination drive in your system most probably confuses the Windows installation. Unplugging the secondary drives would also prevent you from encountering the so-called OS Confusion.

Once you have successfully installed Windows OS on the primary/booting SSD, plug back the secondary drives and reformat them through Disk Management, if needed. You might also find this [Windows Install & Optimization Guide for SSDs & HDDs](http://www.overclock.net/t/1240779/seans-windows-8-install-optimization-guide-for-ssds-hdds) pretty useful.

Hope this helps you. :) 
Good luck!